# Adding items to order as order is placed

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, addtocart

I am trying to add a zero cost product to all shopping carts at time of placing order.  So far I have my observer setup and working as

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_before>
        <observers>
            <custom_promopack_order_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>custom_promopack/observer</class>
                <method>addPromoPack</method>
            </custom_promopack_order_observer>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_before>
</events>
```

For my observer class I start with

```
class Custom_PromoPack_Model_Observer
{

public function addPromoPack(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)

{

    $productId = 2;
    $qty = 1;
    $promo = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $quote = $order->getQuote();
    $item  = $observer->getQuoteItem();

    $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')
        ->setProduct($promo)
        ->setQuote($quote)
        ->setQty($qty)
        ->save();

    $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote')
        ->itemToOrderItem($quoteItem)
        ->setOrderID($order->getId())
        ->save();

}
}
```

The above is throwing the error

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote::itemToOrderItem() must be an instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract, null given
```

However when I replace the $quoteItem with

```
$item->setProduct($promo)
        ->setQuote($quote)
        ->setQty($qty)
        ->save();
```

It successfully adds the item to the order, except it adds it with the price of the original item added.  Thankfully this does not actually increase the price of the cart, but I can tell it is not completely working as intended due to this.

How can I add the item I am intending while keeping the cost of the item at zero? To sum everything up, I am just attempting to grab the order add on a free item and save it to the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the price from the original item is taken in your second exmaple, because you take your quote item and just change the actual product in the quote item (the price is saved in the quote item seperately because the actual product price may change in the future while the price in the quote should always be the same)

So, your first example would be the correct start. But, the $quoteItem->save() returns null.

This might be a Magento issue, since the save() method is implemented here in the Quote Item Model https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php#L923 and does not return the actual Model instance like it should: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php

So you should be good with your first example (not sure if you have to set additional data) by implementing it like this:

```
$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')
        ->setProduct($promo)
        ->setQuote($quote)
        ->setQty($qty);
$quoteItem->save();
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly the issue, the $quoteItem now saves properly and therefore gets added. Thanks